# Can't connect Rails-project to localhost when computer is connected to internet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost

I just recently begun having the problem that I'm only able to visit localhost:3000 when **wifi is turned off and computer is disconnected from the internet.**

As soon as I turn on wifi and connect the computer to an internet connection, chrome just says "connecting" in bottom left corner of browser window. **There are no errors present.**

I've tried on three completely different connections. Home wifi, office and hotspotting via phone.

I have also tried on several different Rails-projects, both rails 5 and below. So it doesn't seem to be project-related.

I have also tried booting the server using my computers IP address as well as 0.0.0.0, and as well as on a different port than :3000. I've also tried in different browsers.

If it is to any use:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://xxx.xx.xx.x:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use `rails generate simple_form:install` to generate the Simple Form configuration.
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.7.0 (ruby 2.2.4-p230), codename: Snowy Sagebrush
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Observation:

This error does not affect rendering partials asynchronously inside the view. That is as smooth and quick as it use to be. This only happens when trying to go from `projects/:id/edit` to `projects/new` for instance.

Comment: What command did you try to start the server? Can you try once with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`?

Comment: I've tried both plain `rails s` to boot server on port :3000, I've used `rails s -p 3001` to boot using another port - I've tried `rails s -b xxx.xx.xx.xx` (to boot using my IP address), but problem is the same nonetheless. It simply wont connect unless computer is offline.

Comment: No, sorry - 0.0.0.0 isn't working either.

Comment: _No, sorry - 0.0.0.0 isn't working either_ -- What exactly didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as you say, there are no errors and AJAX calls are working smoothly, I'd say that you are using an asset that is fetched from the internet but is not available right now. While the internet is working, the application will keep waiting for a response from the remote server.

When you disconnect from the internet and load the page, see if you get any errors in the browser console about failing to fetch something and try removing it from your application. Let me know if this turns out to be your issue.

Comment: Bom. You got it. Im using a font-service no longer available. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Crashtor Anytime!